# Why males are more prone to cardiovascular diseases such as heart attacks than females?

Tags: human-biology, pharmacology, endocrinology

I often see more people of males undergoing treatment for heart disease. It is often said that female reproductive hormone (oestrogen) has some cardio-protective action by preventing constriction of coronary arteries. Can any one explain this?

Comment: Can you please provide some reference to support the statement? Your observations can be biased and the sample size may be too small to make such claims.

Answer (score 0):

A potential cause is the different distributions of body fat in males and females.

Men typically store their fat in their midsections and women store it in their hips/legs.

Ectopic fat, a type that puts people at a greater risk of cardiovascular disease, is stored more in the midsection of people.

Therefore, men are more likely to get cardiovascular diseases.

https://press.rsna.org/timssnet/media/pressreleases/14_pr_target.cfm?ID=1983